# System.InvalidOperationException when trying to bind a CefSharp.WPF event to ViewModel

Tags: caliburn.micro, cefsharp

I've got a View with a CefSharp.WPF component embedded in it, and I need to be notified when it's initialized, and when it's loading etc.

Because there are no conventions for this built into Caliburn.Micro I've used cal:Message.Attach like so:

```
    <cefsharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Name="Browser" Visibility="Visible" TabIndex="3"
                                 WebBrowser="{Binding WebBrowser, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                 Address="http://localhost:8080/"
                                 Title="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                 cal:Message.Attach="[Event FrameLoadStart] = [Action OnLoading()]"/>
```

In my View Model I then have a simple action:

```
    public void OnLoading()
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Loading");
    }
```

However, when I start the application it almost immediately throws a System.InvalidOperationException because it's trying to access something on another thread.

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
>   Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Is there any way around this - to make sure the action is called on the proper thread (or vice versa), or is there a better way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: You need to marshal your call to `System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Loading");` onto the `UI` thread using the `Dispatcher`. I'm not familiar with `Caliburn` so I cannot provide you with specifics.

Comment: Unfortunately, even without anything in that method, just the method being called trips the exception. It looks like my ViewModel is residing in a different thread to the CefSharp.WPF control.

Comment: All of the events in `CefSharp` are called on `CEF` threads, so if you wish to use anything `UI` related you have to marshal your code using the `Dispatcher`. I'm not sure how `Caliburn` handles it's internal mapping between event and action.

Comment: Execute is where most of the dispatcher related code resides.  Its a static class with other methods associated to marshal to the UI